# Jquery UI Dialog in MVC4 application loading dialog content from partial view

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

This question is really asking for direction on how to proceed expanding this simple example and to see if I'm approaching the problem the right way.

This is my first use of Jquery UI. I am invoking the below jquery UI dialog (which works fine) on a click event. The dialog will contain a number of elements (checkboxes etc) that when clicked will perform an action on the element that invoked the dialog in the first place. (The 'this' in showdialog(this))

1) You'll see that I'm establishing click events for the dialog elements which gets called in the open event of dialog(). There will be a number of these so I'm wondering if this is the correct place to do this.

2) The dialog might get complex, so I don't want to use .html() to load the content, I want to use a partial view (or similar.) I tried adding $(this).load('@Url.Action("controllername")') to the Start action. The content loaded fine, but the click events were lost. So, I moved dialogevents() to the partial view, but it still didn't work and actually seemed to crash Chrome when I clicked on the checkboxes.

Can anyone who's been through this before give me any suggestions on a) preferred way to load content into the dialog, and b) best way to manage click events for the elements inside the dialog.

Or...should I not use .dialog() for this. :)

Thanks.

```
   <script>
        $(function (e) {            
                $(".Text").on("click", function (e) {
                    showdialog(this);
                });
            }

            function showdialog(obj) {
                var customdialog = $('<div id="customdialog"></div>')                
                .html('<h2>Hello World</h2><br>Color: <input class="thischeckbox" type="checkbox" name="color" value="checked"> <input class="thatcheckbox" type="checkbox" name="columns" value="checked">')
                .dialog({
                    modal: false,
                    dialogClass: "contentpopup",
                    title: "Here's My Modal",
                    height: 500,
                    width: 300,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        //$(this).load('@Url.Action("LoadDialog")');
                        dialogevents();
                    }
                });

                function dialogevents() {
                    $(".thischeckbox").on("click", function () {
                        alert("this clicked!");

                    $(".thatcheckbox").on("click", function () {
                        alert("that clicked!");
                    });
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
```

this is what I used when I tried load the partial view...

Controller:

```
public ActionResult LoadDialog()
{
    return PartialView("LoadDialog");
}
```

LoadDialog.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}


<div>
        <h2>Hello World</h2><br>Color: <input class="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" name="color" value="checked"> <input class="columncheckbox" type="checkbox" name="columns" value="checked">
</div>

<script>
    $(function dialogevents(obj) {
      //same as above
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you aren't just simply putting your view into a div and performing a `.dialog()` on it...?!

In your first view:

```
<div id="divDialog" style="display:none">
    @Html.Partial("MyPartialView")
</div>
```

Whenever you want the dialog:

```
$("#divDialog").dialog({
    // dialog options...
});
```

You can also render any contents dynamically into your dialog:

```
$("#divDialog").html(jqXHR.responseText); // or any hard coded content
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree with using @Html.Partial() but otherwise it's the same thing done a slightly different way. The only difference is whether the div already exists or if it's created dynamically. The perplexing thing is why the click events cause the browser to crash (by which I mean processor usage goes to 50 percent and I have to kill the process)

Comment: My problem in moving to the partial view was that the click functions no longer had the context of the element that invoked the dialog in the first place. Or to put it more succintly, I'm an idiot.